# Android app crashes at runtime after successful gradle build

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, nullpointerexception, adapter

I'm new to `android` and `firestore`. I have built a small app and whenever I run my app, the app crashes at runtime eventhough the gradle build is successful. The following is the code for the main activity and `Logcat` for the better understanding.

```
package com.example.make;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentChange;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.EventListener;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.Nullable;

import io.opencensus.tags.Tag;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String Tag = "Firelog";

private List<Users> usersList;
private UsersListAdapter usersListAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    RecyclerView mMainList = findViewById(R.id.main_list);

    usersList  = new ArrayList<>();
    usersListAdapter = new UsersListAdapter(usersList);
    mMainList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
    mMainList.setAdapter(usersListAdapter);


    TextView mName = findViewById(R.id.item_name);
    TextView mStatus = findViewById(R.id.item_status);

    try {

        FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        db.collection("Users").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

                if (e != null) {

                    Log.d(Tag, "Error : " + e.getMessage(), new NullPointerException());


                    for (DocumentChange doc : queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {

                        if (doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {

                            doc.getDocument().getReference().collection("Users").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                                    if (e != null) {
                                        Log.d("", "Error :" + e.getMessage(), new NullPointerException());
                                    }

                                    for (DocumentChange doc : queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {

                                        if (doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {

                                            Log.d("USer Name :", doc.getDocument().getId());
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            });

                            Users users = doc.getDocument().toObject(Users.class);
                            usersList.add(users);
                            usersListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        });
    } catch (NullPointerException error) {
        mName.setText(error.getMessage());
    }
}

}
```

This is the error I get,

> 12-03 13:59:30.576 26036-26036/com.example.make E/AndroidRuntime:
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.make, PID: 26036
>       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.List
>   com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot.getDocumentChanges()' on a
>   null object reference
>           at com.example.make.MainActivity$1.onEvent(MainActivity.java:65)
>           at com.example.make.MainActivity$1.onEvent(MainActivity.java:56)
>           at com.google.firebase.firestore.Query.lambda$addSnapshotListenerInternal$2(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.3:885)
>           at com.google.firebase.firestore.Query$$Lambda$3.onEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.3)
>           at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.ExecutorEventListener.lambda$onEvent$0(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.3:42)
>           at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.ExecutorEventListener$$Lambda$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.3)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6383)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)

I also put the `try catch` block to catch the nullpointer exception but it didn't work.Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: QuerySnapshot object is null. check MainActivity.java on line 65

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error states that :

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.List com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot.getDocumentChanges()' on a null object reference

And inside your code:

```
for (DocumentChange doc : queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {
```

The queryDocumentSnapshots object is null (as can be inferred by the annotation).

Comment: @BharatPadhiyar - If my answer helped you, please mark it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
    if(queryDocumentSnapshots != null){
       for (DocumentChange doc : queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {
           if (doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {
              Log.d("USer Name :", doc.getDocument().getId());
           }
       }
    }
}
```

As the method clearly annotates, QuerySnapshot is nullable, so you have to add null check.

Comment: I also remove the dependence of firebase core and change the rules of darabase lock mode to test mode